# Can't connect to Wired Network after installing 12.04

Tags: 12.04, networking

I have installed 12.04 into a used HP Compaq DC 7100 CMT. Plugged in LAN cable into the computer and it says network disconnected. from what I understand on the things I've read, it's not getting the address right, maybe it's just a guess (hardware address 00:16:35:78:47:bb).

I know the LAN cable is working I can get on the net with the old computer. (Old computer is using device MAC address; Auto eth0 00:11:11:E6:4F:FE).

I have put this address into the newer HP and it shows last used (minutes ago) but no Internet sever not found. I tried the hardware address it says never.

I feel and think this should be easy to fix. But I just don't know.

Here is the info everyone has asked for, but they never say what I should do.

```
sudo lshw -C network; rfkill list; cat /etc/network/interfaces; cat /etc/lsb-release; lspci -nn; lsusb; uname -a;
ifconfig; route -n

*-network
               description: ethernet interface
               product; NetXtreme BCM5751 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express
               vendor: Broadcom Corporation
               physical id: 0
               bus info: pci@0000:40:00.0
               logical name: eth0
              verson: 01
              serial: 00:16:35:78:47:bb
              size: 100Mbit/s
              capacity: 1Gbit/s
              width: 64 bits
              clock: 33MHz
              capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000-fd
              configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=
3.121 duplex=full firmware=5751-v3.29a latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twi
sted pair speed=100Mbit/s
             resources: irq:17 memory:f0400000-f040ffff
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION= "Ubuntu 12.04 LTS"
00:00.0 host bridge [0600]: Inter Corporation 82915G/P/GV/GL/PL/910GL Memory Con
troller Hub [8086:2580] (rev 04)
00.02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 82915G/GV/910GL inte
grated Graphics Controller [8086:2582] (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family)
 PCI Express Port 1 [8086:2660] (rev 03)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family)
 PCI Express Port 2 [8086:2662] (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Fam
ily) USB UHCI #1 [8086:2658] (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Fam
ily) USB UHCI #2 [8086:2659] (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Fam
ily) USB UHCI #3 [8086:265a] (rev 03)
00:1d.3 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Fam
ily) USB UHCI #4 [8086:265b] (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Fam
ily) USB2 UHCI Controller [8086:265c] (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI bridge [8086:244e] (rev d
3)
00:1e.2 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/
FRW (ICH6 Family) AC'97 Autio conrtroller [8086:266e] (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation 82801FB/RF (ICH6/ICH6R) LPC Interfa
ce Bridge [8086:2640] (rev 03)
00:1f.1 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 fami
ly) IDE Controller [8086:266f] (rev 03)
00:1f.2 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FW (ICH6/ICH6W) SATA Con
troller [8086:2651] (rev 03)
40:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXreme BCM5751 Gigab
it Ethernet PCI Express [14e4:1677} (rev 01)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Linux bob-desktop 3.2.0-23-generic-pae #36-Ubuntu SMP Tpr 10 22:19:09 UTC 20
12 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:16:35:78:47:bb
                    inet6 addr: fe80::216:35ff:47bb/64 Scope:link
                    UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
                    RX packets:2517 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
                    TX packets:164 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
                    collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
                   RX bytes:164508 (164.5 KB) TX bytes: 40884 (40.0 KB)
                   Interrupt:17

lo Link encap:Local loopback
                   inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
                   inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
                   UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:16436 Metric:1
                   RX packets:3290 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
                   TX packets:3290 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
                   collisions:0 txqueuelen: 0
                   RX bytes:267212 (267.2 KB) TX bytes: 267212 (267.2 KB)

Kernel Ip routing table
Destination Gateway Genmask Flags Metric Ref Use Iface

ran this
  sudo dhclient eth0
  no reply

ran this
  ip addr

1: lo <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
       link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
       inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       inet6 ::1/128 scope host
            valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST ,MULTICAST ,UP ,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
       link/enter 00:16:35:78:47:BB brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
       inet 169.254.7.172/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope link eth0:avahi
       inet6 fe80::216:35ff:fe78:47bb/64 scope link
             valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Help please.

Answer (score 1):

Through other discussions, you mentioned you are using a SURFboard for your cablemodem, but you don't mention a firewall or router.

You will have to reboot the SURFboard each time you plug in a different computer - this will let the new computers MAC address get an IP address.

I strongly suggest you purchase an inexpensive home firewall/router, then you can have both computers on at once if necessary and they will be protected a bit more.

Comment: plug in a NIC card did what you said and still not connected to the Internet. but network connection 1 &2 says last used 3 minutes ago. boy am I at a lost on this one.

Comment: Just to confirm, you're using DHCP to assign the addresses of both the good and bad systems, correct?  Even if they are using the same cable, they should both get unique IP addresses that are both in the same subnet.

Comment: I would have to say no. (I'm a new-bee) you lost me on that one I am new to this computer stuff. can you brake it down and talk me through each steep. I will look up what your saying to learn more.

Comment: Can you describe what your LAN consists of?  (i.e. cable or DSL modem, firewall make/model, etc)  You also mentioned re-using the "known good" cable between two machines.  Can you get a second patch cable and plug both machines into the network at the same time?

Comment: Lan goes to a cable modem (make & model) is motorola SB5100 SERFboard

Comment: http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=motorola%20sb5100%20surfboard%20cable%20modem&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.firstmedia.com%2Fdownload%2Ffastnet%2FPanduan%2520Pelanggan%2520FastNet%2520Cable%2520Modem%2520Motorola%2520SB5101.pdf&ei=qaRgUO-JAaet0QWJnoDADg&usg=AFQjCNHIAnn8XlvaO5kaENZRNYLVpxnUxw&cad=rja

Comment: I was thinking of getting another LAN cable and running the newer computer to the older one, but then I have two computers running, when I only need one. is there a advantage to doing this

Comment: Having two machines on the same network allows for easier troubleshooting (i.e. "can you ping from machine A to machine B", etc).

Comment: You said "Lan cable goes to a cable modem", correct?  Is it directly to the cable modem, or is there a firewall/router between them?

Comment: The SURFboard only has a single RF45 port.  If I recall correctly, the SURFboard needs to be rebooted each time a new device is plugged into it.  Please try connecting the "Bad" computer to the SURFboard, then powering the SURFboard off for 30 seconds, then back on.  Wait a minute for the SURFboard to come up completely, then check if the "Bad" computer can get out to the internet.

Comment: WOW :) so easy yet no one could get it right, you are The King!! one thing I turn the modem off then back on it did nothing. I unplug the modem from it's power, then plugged it back in and bang, got Internet. may great things always come to you. THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Glad to have helped. I'll post more details to my original answer - please accept it as the answer when you get a chance.

Comment: ezz9 - Would you mind clicking "Accept" on this answer so I can get credit for helping you?  That's how the site works.

Comment: @ezz9 - Would you please mark the answer as accepted answer by clicking on the grey tick mark?  Thanks!